# How can I set style on my child component?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having this div where I am showing the input next to the `chips` divs.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-wsyrzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

As you can see I set on the parent the class - `tags-input__tags` and I used the following css on that class

```
.tags-input__tags {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The problem for me happens the moment when I try to de-couple my form, so first I tried to put the chips html into separate component called - `Chips`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-zd4uvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips%2Fchips.component.ts

After I did that, my HTML is broken. I don't know how can I make my html looks the same after like in the first example where I did not had other component.

I tried setting the css styles also with `:host ::ng-deep` but without success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the desired output by putting the following `css` in `chips.components.css`

```css
:host {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: No, on that way i will say display flex only on the chips component - i need display flex on the outer div for the `app-chips` component and the input it self.

Comment: When there are a lot of chips - then input will go always down, i need it to be inline

Comment: if you want to keep chips and input inline. remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from `:host ::ng-deep .tags-input__tags`. but input will become smaller when you add more chips, to handle that you have set overflow css.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please fork my stackblitz and provide an example ?

Comment: look into it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-hvo9mt?file=src/app/app.component.scss

Comment: It is still not the same. I don't have flex-wrap: wrap on the wrapper - i need that so when there are a lot of chips the input will be wrapped down with them.

Comment: If i add flex-wrap: wrap on your example then - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-jmfthj?file=src/app/app.component.scss - i get the input always on the right

Comment: I'm not sure what is your actual requirement.

Comment: See my first example and yours and you will see the diference.,